# ElasticSearch aggregation returns always 10 buckets only

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST. The number of buckets returned from ElasticSearch aggregation is always 10 (default value), in spite of the fact that the size is set to 10000
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the size inside the Terms aggregation and not outside of it. Try this:

```
.Aggregations( a => a
   .Terms(category_agg", st => st
       .Field(o => o.categories.Select(x => x.id))
       .Size(10000)
   )
)
```